# How can I change these codes to C#.net framework 3.5?

Tags: c#

Here is the code of .net framework 4.0.
But our old system is using 3.5. It's difficult to upgrade all the codes.
I want to know how to change the codes written by 4.0 to 3.5 codes.

The main problem is I don't know how to convert "return string.Join(",", states);"
Error happened when I was trying to compile it using .net framework 3.5.

Thank you!

```
public enum States
{
....
}

public static string GetStates(uint stateFlags)
{
    var stateList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(States));
    var states = default(States);

    foreach (var state in stateList)
    {
        if (state == null) continue;
        var stateEnum = (States)state;
        if (HasState(stateFlags, stateEnum))
        {
            states = states | stateEnum;
        }
    }

    return string.Join(",", states);
}
```

The error is
Error   The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You should always specify exactly what error happens -- just copy and paste it into the question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.The error is "The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments".

Comment: That code looks like it will have the same error in .Net 4, so I don't know what you're expecting.

Comment: `states` is an enum no .net version accepts an enum in `String.Join()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version of your original solution

```
public enum States
{
    None = 0,
    StateOne = 1,
    StateTwo = 2,
    StateThree = 4,
    StateFour = 8,
};

public static string GetStates(uint stateFlags)
{
    var stateList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(States));
    List<States> states = new List<States>();

    foreach (int state in stateList)
    {        
        if ((stateFlags & state) != 0)
        {
            states.Add((States)state);
        }
    }

    return string.Join(",", states);
}
```

Running

`GetStates((uint)(States.StateOne | States.StateTwo))`

outputs

`StateOne,StateTwo`

Answer (score 5):

`string.Join` in .Net 3.5 only supports a string array whereas .Net 4.0 has additional overloads to work with `IEnumerable<string>` or `Object[]`.

You should be passing a `string[]` to the `Join` method.

More at the MSDN docs:

> .Net 4 :
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.100).aspx
>
> .Net 3.5:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: In the sample above, the variable "states" is of type "States", so there is no ToArray extension method on it...

Comment: Thank you! I tried it, but it can't be compiled. The error is : "'States' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'States' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 1):

In .Net 3.5 the overload you used for "String.Join" is not available. 
Replace your return row with the following 2 rows:

```
 string[] stateNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(States));
 return string.Join(",", stateNames);
```

The expected second argument is an array of Strings.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you mean the code below have now use?      foreach (var state in stateList)
    {
        if (state == null) continue;
        var stateEnum = (States)state;
        if (HasState(stateFlags, stateEnum))
        {
            states = states | stateEnum;
        }
    }

Comment: @user1836330: I am not sure what you mean by "the code below have now use". Are you asking if it is necessary for the function to work?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your warmly help.
I changed the last line to below:

```
        var valuesAsList = GetValues(states).Cast<string>().ToList();

        return string.Join(",", valuesAsList.ToArray());
```

And added the method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Enum> GetValues(Enum enumeration)
    {
        List<Enum> enumerations = new List<Enum>();
        foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in enumeration.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            enumerations.Add((Enum)fieldInfo.GetValue(enumeration));
        }
        return enumerations;
    }
```

The compile error disappeared, but I still haven't test the code to see whether it's the same result with .net 4.0.

Thanks again.